# Hibernate @OneToOne gives error

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities `Item`.

They are linked with entity `Link`

Each item can have many links, but link is a connection between two items.

The problem is that the order of items is important. One is always the first `item` and other is second `item`.

So my entities are like this:

```
Item
   private Collection<Link> links = new ArrayList<Link>();
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = ????)
    public Collection<Link> getLinks() {
       return links;
   }

Link
private Item firstItem;
private Item secondItem;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = ???)
public Item getFirstItem() {
    return firstItem;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy = ???)
public Item getSecondItem() {
    return secondItem;
}
```

What should i put to `mappedBy`?? Because pseudomapping for `Item` should me smthin like this:
`mappedBy = { "firstItem", "secondItem") }`

At first I had no mapping and this gives error:

```
 @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on foo.bar.Item.links references an unknown entity: java.util.Collection
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting something, but how are going to map a collection with @OneToOne?

Comment: To amplify what @DenisTulskiy said: you *cannot* map a collection with `@OneToOne`. Also, you need to use `@OneToMany`. You probably need to have two collections, one for `Link`s where that `Item` is the first, and one for those where it is the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create two different collections with `mappedBy` pointing to `firstItem` and `secondItem`, respectively.

If you need to view them as a single collection, do it in code.

Also as already noted you need to use `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` instead of `@OneToOne`. `@ManyToOne` doesn't need `mappedBy`.

Comment: Two collections seem logical.